# How to return a range of result in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When using SQLAlchemy, we can use q.all() to return all data or use q.limit(xx) to return the data by specified number.

However, how to get data begin with the (X)th term and size is y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `offset()` and `limit()`

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.offset - `offset()`
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.limit - `limit()`

Try like this

```
session.query(SomeClass). \
    offset(x). \
    limit(y). \
    all()
```